# How to prove this series is absolute convergent?

Tags: functional-analysis, absolute-convergence

Assume $X$ is a Hilbert space, $\{e_n\}_{ n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthogonal set of $X$. Let $x=∑α_ne_n$， $y=∑β_ne_n$.

Prove $(\mathrm{x}, \mathrm{y})=\sum_{\mathrm{n}=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{\mathrm{n}} \bar{\beta}_{\mathrm{n}}$, and the series on the right of the equality is absolute convergent.

I use a method：
Let $\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\alpha_{n}\right| e_{n} \quad \beta=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\beta_{n}\right| e_{n}$
Then take $(α,β)$ and then get the conclusion(for a inner product is a certain value).
Is this proof right? I don't think the 'Hilbert' is useful here. Could I just extend this conclusion to a normol inner product space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I used "orthonormal" for your $\{e_n\}$ instead of "orthogonal", which adds a few complications)*

Repeat with me: *a series is not sum*. A series is a *limit of sums*. So to be able to talk about series you need to be able to talk about limits: thus you need a topology. And, equally importantly, for the limits to exist you need your space to be *complete*. In an arbitrary inner product space, you will likely have Cauchy sequences which are not convergent. That's why we care about Hilbert spaces.

In particular, in a non-complete inner product space you might have (using your notation from above) that $x\in X$ but $\alpha$ doesn't exist.

That said, your method will lead nowhere: there is no useful relation between your $\alpha$ and your $x$. What they want you to do here is the following: first show that $\sum_n\alpha_n\overline{\beta_n}$ converges absolutely. This is due to Cauchy-Schwarz: 
$$
\sum_n|\alpha_n\overline{\beta_n}|=\sum_n|\alpha_n|\,|{\beta_n}|\leq\left(\sum_n|\alpha_n|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_n|{\beta_n}|^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
and the two series on the right converge because $x$ and $y$ exist. Namely, you know that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for any $n_1,n_2>n_0$
$$
\left\|\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2} \alpha_ne_n\right\|^2<\varepsilon. 
$$
The left-hand-side above is precisely $\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2}|\alpha_n|^2$. So you obtain that $\sum_n|\alpha_n|^2<\infty$. Similarly with $y$ and $\beta_n$.

Now using that the inner product (proof below) is continuous (you might have to prove this, too)
\begin{align}
(x,y)&=\left(\sum_n\alpha_ne_n,\sum_n{\beta_n}e_n\right)=\lim_m\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\alpha_ne_n,\sum_{n=1}^m{\beta_n}e_n\right)\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_m\sum_{k,n=1}^m\alpha_n\overline{\beta_k}(e_n,e_k)
=\lim_m\sum_{n=1}^m\alpha_n\overline{\beta_n}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n\overline{\beta_n}
\end{align}

---

**Proof that the inner product is continuous:** suppose that $z_n\to z$ and $w_n\to w$ in $X$. Then, using Cauchy=Schwarz,
$$
(z_n,w_n)-(z,w)=(z_n-z,w_n)+(z,w_n-w)\leq \|z_n-z\|\,\|w_n\|+\|z\|\,\|w_n-w\|\to0
$$
if we show that $\|w_n\|<c$ for a fixed $c$. This follows from $w_n\to w$. For $n$ big enough, $\|w_n-w\|<1$. Then $\|w_n\|=\|w_n-w+w\|\leq\|w_n-w\|+\|w\|<1+\|w\|$.